# ImageMagick - change the background color of the selected bounding box

Tags: imagemagick, background-image, crop, bounding-box

I already have the normalized vertices of my selected bounding box (e.g xmin: 0.68, ymin: 0.47, xmax: 0.94, ymax: 0.82) and I want to save this box in an other .jpg file. Furthermore, in the original image I want to make this highlighted box all white. Is this possible using Imagemagick?

Comment: Please add some context to your question. How can a bounding box be expressed as a floating point number? Please show starting image and corresponding expected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with this:

[image]

and knowing the top-left corner of the monument is at `400,10` and the bottom-right is at `500,200`, you can extract the monument to a file with:

```
magick photo.jpg -crop 100x190+400+10 extract.jpg
```

[image]

and overpaint in white with:

```
magick photo.jpg -fill white -draw "rectangle 400,10 500,200" overpainted.jpg
```

[image]

Or, for extra fun, overpaint in semi-transparent white with:

```
magick photo.jpg -fill "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" -draw "rectangle 400,10 500,200" overpainted.jpg
```

[image]

---

You can do both operations in one go with:

```
magick photo.jpg \( +clone -fill white -draw "rectangle 400,10 500,200" -write overpainted.jpg +delete \) -crop 100x190+400+10 extract.jpg
```

Comment: Why in the -crop you used 100x190+400+10? I mean, 400+10 is the top left corner but 100x190 what is?

Comment: The crop command uses `width` and `height`, so these are the **differences** between the x and the y values rather than their absolute positions. Sorry, I could have explained that better in my answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you! If, instead, I want to use version 6 of ImageMagick what I have to change?

Answer (score 3):

Using ImageMagick version 6, the command below will create two output images. (An example command for ImageMagick version 7 is further down in the reply.)

The first output image will be cropped from the input image using the bounding box starting at w*0.68xh*0.47 and ending at w*0.94xh*0.82.

The second output will be the input with a white section corresponding to the sub-image cropped out to make the first image.

```
convert input.png \
   -set option:distort:viewport "%[fx:(w*0.94)-(w*0.68)]x%[fx:(h*0.82)-(h*0.47)]" \
   \( +clone -distort affine "0,0 -%[fx:w*0.68],-%[fx:h*0.47]" \
   -write result1.png -fill white -colorize 100 \) \
   -set page "%[fx:u.w]x%[fx:u.h]+%[fx:t*(u.w*0.68)]+%[fx:t*(u.h*0.47)]" \
   -flatten result2.png
```

That starts by reading the input image and calculating the viewport, the dimensions of the sub-image to crop, according to the bounding box dimensions you've provided.

Then inside the parentheses it creates a clone and does a "-distort affine" which, in effect, crops the image and locates it properly in that viewport. It writes that result to the first output image "result1.png". Then, still inside the parentheses, it fills that cropped piece with white.

After that it sets the paging geometry so that white piece can eventually be composited back into its original location over the input image.

It finishes by flattening the white piece onto the input image, and writes the second output image "result2.png".

The same thing can be done using ImageMagick version 7 with a slightly less complicated command...

```
magick input.png \
   \( +clone \
   -crop "%[fx:(w*0.94)-(w*0.68)]x%[fx:(h*0.82)-(h*0.47)]+%[fx:w*0.68]+%[fx:h*0.47]" \
   -write result1.png -fill white -colorize 100 \) \
   -flatten result2.png
```

That does the calculations directly in the "-crop" operation, and the paging geometry is saved in the cropped piece so it can be flattened back to its original position without resetting the geometry.

Those are in *nix syntax. To make it work in Windows change the continued line backslashes "\" to carets "^", and eliminate those backslashes that escape the parentheses "\(...\)".

Answer (score 1):

Here is one other variation in ImageMagick 6. It crops the image and saves it and then deletes it. Then it use -region to write white into that bounding box.

This is Unix syntax. For Windows, remove \ from parenthesis and change end of line \ to ^.

Input:

[image]

```
convert img.jpg \
\( +clone -crop 100x190+400+10 +repage +write result1.jpg +delete \) \
-region 100x190+400+10 -fill white -colorize 100 +region result2.jpg
```

[image]

[image]